# manage.py syncdb on windows for Google App Engine Patch does not work

Tags: windows, django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-patch

I have installed Google App Engine patch and I get the following error when I want to sync the DB

Command on command prompt on windows

```
manage.py syncdb

The Google App Engine SDK could not be found!Visit http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-  patch/ for installation instructions.
```

I have installed win32api too and it still recurs. appcfg.py and dev_appserver.py works normally.

EDIT

Added and removed following paths from PATH

```
F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google
F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib
```

EDIT
The following hack has made it working but I hope there is a better way

```
SDK_PATH = "F:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine"
```

in 
aecmd.py in common\appenginepatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more [reading](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/app-engine-patch.html) helped , and thanx to Jesaja Everling

specifically the line

> If you were using Django with a
>   relational database, you would now
>   have to run manage.py syncdb to create
>   the necessary database tables. With
>   App Engine this happens on the fly.

Additionally, improved the hack to

```
    if os.name in ('nt', 'dos'):
        #Below path only considers C:\\Program Files
        #prefix = '%(PROGRAMFILES)s' % os.environ
        #paths.append(prefix + r'\Google\google_appengine')        
        #check all drives for path 
        for path in os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(';'):
            if path.endswith('google_appengine') or path.endswith('google_appengine\\') :
                paths.append(path)
```

PROGRAMFILES gives only C: by default and my google_appengine is in F: